# Why can't we print out the pytz.country_timezones dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, timezone

Why can' we print out the whole dictionary like the way we print out any normal dictionary?

`print(pytz.country_timezones)`

gives:

`<pytz._CountryTimezoneDict object at 0x00FCC700>`

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `pytz` has a special `dict` implementation, that doesn't has a repr. The `repr` is not defined because the implementation is lazy, which creates the dict one key at the time when this key is asked for.

You can print it with `print(dict(pytz.country_timezones))`, which will turn it to a regular dict.

You can look at the specifiec implementaition [here](https://github.com/newvem/pytz/blob/f137ff00112a9682bc4e4945067b3b88f158d010/pytz/__init__.py#L180), notice the `_country_timezones_cache` variable.